# how to binding at runtime in google guice

Tags: java, binding, guice

I am using Java ASM to generate implement classes of several `Interface` at runtime . i've add `@Singleton` annotation on the top of the Class Name , but i still can't get the Instance by Injector.getInstance(InterfaceName). those generate process happens in a module .
my question is , how to do binding at runtime with guice.

Comment: `@Singleton` doesn't create the actual binding, all it does is make sure there is only ever one instance of the class. Checkout https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Bindings.